# Match lines before empty new line

Tags: c#, regex

The input is like this:

```
0
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Hello world!

1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Hello world!
This is my new world.

2
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Hello guys!
```

Using a clear and fast regex, I want to split that into:

```
Match 1: `0`
Match 2: `00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000`
Match 3: `Hello world!`

Match 1: `1`
Match 2: `00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000`
Match 3: `Hello world!
This is my new world.`

Match 1: `2`
Match 2: `00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000`
Match 3: `Hello guys!`
```

I use `(\d+)[\n\r]([\d:,]+\s-->\s[\d:,]+)[\n\r].+` for matching, but the problem is It does not match **two line of text or more** (match 3 in group 2 of the above example).

*Note:* If you know a way with good readability and better performance without using Regex, feel free to offer me that.

Thanks,
Alireza

Comment: please tell us what language you are using

Comment: @AvinashRaj As I mentioned before, total lines maybe are more than two lines. Your Regex only support two lines. Then that is not what I want, but thanks.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Thanks, I've just edited my post.

Comment: Any reason you particularly want to use a regex for this?

Comment: @JonSkeet No if there is a way with good readability and better performance.

Comment: So can you give us more background about the context? Are you reading this data from a file, or do you already have it as a string? What form do you want the result in? (e.g. a `List<List<string>>`?)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon. I'm reading the data from a file and I want the result in a `MatchCollection` if It possible (if not, `List<string>` is better I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's a non-regex approach:

```
public IEnumerable<List<string>> ReadSeparatedLines(string file)
{
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file))
    {
        if (line == "")
        {
            // Only take action if we've actually got something to return. This
            // handles files starting with blank lines, and also files with
            // multiple consecutive blank lines.
            if (lines.Count > 0)
            {
                yield return lines;
                lines = new List<string>();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }
    // Check whether we had any trailing lines to return
    if (lines.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return lines;
    }
}
```

I would *personally* find that easier to understand than a regex, but you may have different tastes, of course.

Comment: Thanks dear Jon. Your answer is really really helpful and very informative. It works much faster than Regex and has good readability.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex,

```
/(\d+)[\n\r]([\d:,]+\s-->\s[\d:,]+)(.*?)(?=\n\n|$)/sg
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qQ1uQ3/5)

Comment: It really doesn't help! Please check your demo and its match information. a lot of text that You wrote is not matched.

Comment: @Alireza it's matched but not captured . did you want all of them to be captured?

Comment: Yes I do. I want to capture all of text before empty new line.

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
(\d+)[\n\r]([\d:,]+\s-->\s[\d:,]+)[\n](.+(?:[\n]*[^\d|^\n]+)*)
```

result

MATCH 1

1. [0-1]   `0`
2. [2-31]  `00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000`
3. [32-44] `Hello world!`

MATCH 2

1. [46-47] `1`
2. [48-77] `00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000`
3. [78-112]    `Hello world!
   This is my new world.`

MATCH 3

1. [114-115]   `2`
2. [116-145]   `00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000`
3. [146-157]   `Hello guys!`

try at  [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/tV9pS0/3)

**EDIT**

I did try to update the regex for numbers too, so now it match multiple lines, numbers within as needed. now it look bit short too

```
(\d+)[\n](.*?)\n((?s).*?)(?=\n\n\d|\Z)
```

this regex match the following

```
0
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Hello world!

1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Hello world!
This is my new world.

2
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Hello guys!
This line contains 123457!
This is third line!
And more lines!
```

as

MATCH 1

1. [0-1]   `0`
2. [2-31]  `00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000`
3. [32-44] `Hello world!`

MATCH 2

1. [46-47] `1`
2. [48-77] `00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000`
3. [78-112]    `Hello world!
   This is my new world.`

MATCH 3

1. [114-115]   `2`
2. [116-145]   `00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000`
3. [146-220]   `Hello guys!
   This line contains 123457!
   This is third line!
   And more lines!`

try at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/tV9pS0/4)

Comment: As I mentioned before, total lines maybe are more than two lines. Your Regex only support two lines. Then that is not what I want, but thanks.

Comment: i updated after reading some comments for the same, it will match multiple lines now. try the updated one.

Comment: Thanks but It is possible there are numbers between words. In your Regex It is not possible. Then This is not actually what I want.